# SQL Bulk Insert skipping last 849 Lines from Text File

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Good day all! For some reason my bulk Insert statement is skipping the last 849 lines from the text file I am reading. I know this because when I manually add my own last line I don't see it in the table after the insert is done and when debugging I see the message: `(133758 row(s) affected)` and the text file has 134607 Lines, excluding the first 2.

My query looks like this:

```
BULK INSERT #TEMP FROM 'C:\Test\Test.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a', FIRSTROW = 2, MAXERRORS = 50, KEEPNULLS)
```

I have checked if the are more columns then what the table has and that's not the case. I have changed `MAXERRORS` from `10` to `20` to `30` to `40` to `50`, to see if there are any changes but the `Row(s) affected` stays the same. Is there maybe something I haven't handled for or missing?

Thanks awesome people.

P.S. I am using this insert for another text file and table but with different column headers and there are less columns in the text file and it works perfectly.

Comment: What do the lines around your suspect line look like? Often this is caused by bad formatting, e.g. someone has actually managed to type a tab character into one of your fields, so there's an unexpected extra delimiter in a row.

Comment: Formatting is exactly the same The line underneath it like loads of others that have been inserted and the line itself is also correct. I have checked that already. This is a very strange one for me because of it working for other text files. Correct tab separators and column numbers. Same newline chars.

Comment: You have checked this with a hex-editor to be absolutely certain there are no special characters in there?

Comment: Also, make sure to check the line *before* the suspect line. Often it's an error in the previous row that gets things out of step before the line that actually fails.

Comment: I have also the same problem as well, skipping 836 first rows and then add them at the end.